# How to make a dynamic, calculated column? (Swift, SQLite)

Tags: sqlite, sqlite.swift

How i can to make a dynamic, calculated column? Which is calculated using other columns and not stored in the database.
Which can be used for data output and sorting.

Library: stephencelis/SQLite.swift (https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift)

Example:

```
SELECT a+b as c from test ORDER BY c ASC;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With sqlite 3.31.0 and newer, you can use a [generated column](https://sqlite.org/gencol.html).

```sql
CREATE TABLE test(a INTEGER, b INTEGER,
    c INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (a + b) VIRTUAL);
```

Or use a [view](https://sqlite.org/lang_createview.html):

```sql
CREATE TABLE real_test(a INTEGER, b INTEGER);
CREATE VIEW test AS
    SELECT a, b, a + b AS c FROM real_test;
```

Comment: Thanks friend. How can I use it from SQLite.swift ?